# How do i get the `code` that i can exchange later for a access and refresh token both using gapi-script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Currently I have the following code that gives me the access_token, but just to make things more secure i want only the response as a `code`, The code that i can send to the server from the frontend and exchange for a access_token and a refresh_token. How do i do this with `gapi-script` ?

My code currently looks like below :-

```
import './App.css';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { gapi, loadAuth2WithProps} from 'gapi-script';


class MyAppLogin extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const auth2 = await loadAuth2WithProps(
      gapi, 
      {
        client_id: '<MY CLIENT ID>', 
        scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords',
        access_type: 'offline'
      }
    );
    
    this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'), auth2);
  }

  attachSignin (element, auth2) {
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (googleUser) => {
        console.log(googleUser)
      }, (error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="customBtn" className="btn login">
        Login
      </div>
    )
  }

}


export default MyAppLogin;
```

I have digged a bit into this legacy plugin [HERE](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/use-google-login.js#L61), if i use the plugin i get the code successfully if i use the below code :-

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId='<CLIENT ID>'
  onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
  onFailure={this.onFailure}
  responseType='code'
  online='offline'
/>
```

But however i don't want to use this plugin and instead want to use the native `gapi` plugin. Any inputs on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue using [grantOfflineAccess()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthgrantofflineaccessoptions) like below :-

```
attachSignin () {
  const { auth2 } = this.state
  auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(function(resp) {
    var auth_code = resp.code;
    console.log(auth_code)
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div id="customBtn" className="btn login" onClick={this.attachSignin} >
      Login
    </div>
  )
}
```

Was quite confusing a combination of looking into the source code of [react-google-login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/use-google-login.js#L61) (legacy plugin that uses gapi internally) and the above linked google documentation let to this resolution.